# What's the proper word for  a person waiting in a queue?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have tried to use *candidate* or *queue member* to indicate a person waiting in a queue, but the former is not accurate and the latter is not a noun.

Is there a better word for a person waiting in queue?

Comment: "queue member" is indeed a noun. What makes you think it's not?

Comment: "The frustrated"?

Comment: @MarkBeadles I mean a single noun

Comment: You don’t know how much I wish the correct answer were *a cutie*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no contextual example. People queue for various reasons - some are customers, some may be waiting to get into a football game; some may be waiting for an obstruction to be cleared, etc.

Comment: A person waiting in a queue is a clear concept and needs no further context to clarify the question. Examples might restrict to particular cases whereas the question is general. Leave open.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Someone who waits in a queue is a queuer<sup>1</sup>.

For example

> Look at all those queuers queuing! I wonder what they're waiting for.

<sup>1</sup> "queuer, n.". OED Online. June 2012. Oxford University Press. http://oed.com/view/Entry/156388?redirectedFrom=queuer (accessed July 31, 2012).

Comment: You can try these ***queuer***  1. One who, or that which, queues; a person waiting in line [http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/queuer] -- 2. an entity that queues [http://www.websters-online-dictionary.org/definitions/Queuer] and many more at [http://www.google.com/search?q=queuer]

Answer (score 4):

In queueing theory, the common word to refer to people waiting for service is *customers*.

Comment: 'Customer' is adopted as a convenient metaphor in the context you mentioned. The word does not suit the OP's need, though.

Answer (score 2):

In normal speech it’s quite common to simply refer to “the people in the queue”.

Comment: I agree with 'people (or those)in the queue' but 'queuers' must be theoretically correct, if rather ugly, since 'to queue' is indeed a verb.

Comment: @BarryBrown So? English makes nouns from verbs by adding *-er* to them all the time:  *sneakers, accuser, killer, runner, meddler, shooter, tweezers* — just to name a few.

Comment: Indeed - "queuers" is quite correct, but perhaps not as idiomatic.

Answer (score -1):

A queuer would be one who sets up or administers a queue. The person in the queue would be queued which would make them a queuee. This follows the common example of employer, employed, and employee.

Comment: Hello, Huck. English usage does not always follow patterns consistently. Do dictionaries support your suggested definition of 'queuer', or is your suggestion not commonly followed in practice? ELU deals with established usages, which are sometimes not logically predictable.

Comment: This is incorrect.  See the accepted answer for the correct usage.

Comment: An employer employs, they don't create rules for employment (that would be human resources staff or employment lawyers). A singer sings, they don't direct or administer singing (that would be a choirmaster, conductor, or record producer). A baker bakes, they don't administer bakeries (that would be a bakery manager). And of course a queuer queues.